# Автопоиск названий предмета

Tags: delphi

Как сделать таблицу, в которой есть колонка "наименование предмета", при вводе в эту колонку должен срабатывать автопоиск и отображаться название предмета по введенным начальным буквам.

Comment: @Антон Луценко, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: Ах да, еще одна интересная особенность: помощь и выполнение чужой работы стали синонимами почему-то.

Comment: Кто же этот вопрос плюсанул, интересно.

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать...

Воспользоваться, например, TGridEh из пакета EhLib.